# Angular - Manipulate filter condition dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 3 arrays.

```
    var severityFilters = ["High", "Medium", "Low"]

 var ruleFilters = ["true", "false"] 

var allResults = [

{
    "name": "Test1",
    "severity": "High",
    "clean": true
},

{
    "name": "Test2",
    "severity": "Low",
    "clean": false
},

{
    "name": "Test3",
    "severity": "Medium",
    "clean": false
},

{
    "name": "Test4",
    "severity": "High",
    "clean": true
}

]
```

The `severityFilters` array and `ruleFilters` are created dynamically, when user checks and unchecks some filter checkboxes. Therefore, if no `severityFilters` checkboxes are checked, that array would be empty. If only `High` is checked, then `severityFilters` would have `High` in it. Same thing with `ruleFilters` checkboxes.

I would like to write a function to return some filtered results, based on the values in `severityFilters` and `ruleFilters`. The `filterResults` function is called upon a check of each filter checkbox.

```
var filteredResults = []

    filterResults (severityFilters, ruleFilters, allResults)
    {
       for (let i = 0; i < allResults.length; i++) {
            if (severityFilters.length > 0 && ruleFilters.length > 0)
            {
              if (ruleFilters.includes(this.allResults[i].clean.toString()) && 
severityFilters.includes(allResults[i].severity)
              )
              {
                this.filteredResults = [...this.filteredResults, ...allResults[i]];
              }
            }
    }
    }
```

This function works considering both `severityFilters` and `ruleFilters` are specified.

How can I cover checking the filtration for the following scenarios:

1. ruleFilters may be empty
2. severityFilters may be empty.
3. One or more severityFilters are defined, but no ruleFilters exist and vice versa.

Without writing lengthy if conditions, is there a way to tweak the function, such that the results are filtered, no matter the length of `severityFilters` and `ruleFilters` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for `length` of the *filter* arrays before checking whether they includes the property values. If `severityFilters` is empty, `!severityFilters.length` will return true. So, it won't check the second [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) condition because of `||`. If `severityFilters` does have some value, then `severityFilters.includes(o.severity)` will be checked and only those objects with `severity` value in `severityFilters` will be filtered

```js
const severityFilters = ["High"]
const ruleFilters = ["true", "false"]
var allResults=[{name:"Test1",severity:"High",clean:true},{name:"Test2",severity:"Low",clean:false},{name:"Test3",severity:"Medium",clean:false},{name:"Test4",severity:"High",clean:true}];

const output = allResults.filter(o =>
  (!severityFilters.length || severityFilters.includes(o.severity)) &&
  (!ruleFilters.length || ruleFilters.includes(o.clean.toString()))
)

console.log(output)
```

Comment: hmm.. I can't really alter allResults array, like you defined it.

Comment: @Jake I haven't altered `allResults` here

Comment: You have `clean:!0`. It needs to be `false` or `true` only.

Comment: @Jake oh, I'm sorry. I used a minifier to get the array in one line. It converted false to `!0` for some weird reason